# Why is my pagination in codeigniter not working? (404 not found)

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, http-status-code-404

I already follow the step and tutorial. But it's not working.
I already follow tutorial from internet step by step. But it always show 404 page not found when I go to second page

This is my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/blog';
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->mod_blog->getAllData()->num_rows();

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        // $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? ($this->uri->segment(2) - 1) : 0;
        $page = $this->uri->segment(2);

        $data = array(
            'data' => $this->mod_blog->getData($config['per_page'],$page)->result(),
            'pagination' => $this->pagination->create_links()
        );
        $this->load->view('layout/header');
        $this->load->view('layout/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('admin/blog',$data);
        $this->load->view('layout/footer');
    }
```

This is my Model:

```
function getData($limit,$start){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('berita');
        $this->db->join('admin','admin.id_admin = berita.id_admin');
        $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
        $this->db->order_by('id_berita','desc');
        return $this->db->get();
    }

    function getAllData(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('berita');
        $this->db->join('admin','admin.id_admin = berita.id_admin');
        $this->db->order_by('id_berita','desc');
        return $this->db->get();
    }
```

Comment: What does `$page = $this->uri->segment(2);` return? Does it have a value? The line above is commented out. What does that line return if you de-comment it? What, if you leave out the `-1` in the commented line? (I found that in some tutorial)

Comment: it return the page number

Comment: You may need to set up some routes  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, I found my mistake. 
It's in the

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/blog';
```

You must point the config['base_url'] to your baseUrl/controllerName/functionName. So, I changed it into.

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/blog/index';
```

And then I adjust my Uri segment into 3

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;

$page = $this->uri->segment(3);
```